# Parametric family problems

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, marginal-distribution, exponential-family, sufficient-statistics

I came across such a problem that I cannot solve:

Let $\mathcal{P} = \{\mathbb{P}_\theta : \theta \in \mathbb{R}\}$ be a parametric family over $\{0,1\} \times \mathbb{R}$ defined in the following way: the random variable $Z$ has state space $\{0,1\}$ and $\mathbb{P_{\theta}}(Z=0)=\mathbb{P_{\theta}}(Z=1)=\frac{1}{2}$ irrespective of $\theta$, while for parameter value $\theta$, $X|\{Z=1\}\sim N(\theta,2)$ and $X|\{Z=0\} \sim N(\theta,1)$ $($where $A|B$ denotes $A$ conditioned on the event $B$$)$

(a) Do the family of densities of $X$ indexed by $\theta$ form an exponential family?

(b) Show that $X$ is not sufficient for $\theta$.

What I did:

(a) I found the density of $X$ but it is not of the exponential family form and I cannot prove that one can't express it as such.

(b) I don't know how to start

Comment: You might get more helpful answers if you edited your question to tell us what you know and where you are stuck.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do this in the **My Account** section of our [help center](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help)), then you will be able to edit & comment on your own question.